# Convert lambda expression to wrapped class

Tags: c#, lambda

Given the types:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class MyWrapper
{
   public MyWrapper(MyClass myClass)
   {
       MyClass = myClass;
   }

   public MyClass MyClass { get; }
}
```

Is it possible to convert a predicate expression of type `Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<MyWrapper, bool>>`?

e.g. to have a method like this:

```
public Expression<Func<MyWrapper, bool>> Convert(Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> predicate)
{
    return ...
}
```

so that calling `Convert(obj => obj.Prop == "ABC")` would return `wrapper => wrapper.MyClass.Prop == "ABC"`

Comment: You could probably make it easier by having MyWrapper inherit from an interface like `interface IWrapper<T>{ T T {get;}}`. It would be more strong typed and you wouldn't need to mess with expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [ExpressonVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.7.1) to visit body of your passed in predicate and change every occurrence of parameter of type `MyClass` to member access of member `MyClass` of parameter of type `MyWrapper`. In the end you take newly constructed body to construct new lambda expression with parameter of type `MyWrapper` as argument.

Sample of visitor:

```
public class ConverterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ConverterVisitor(ParameterExpression original, Expression convertTo)
    {
        OriginalParameter = original;
        ConvertTo = convertTo;
    }

    public ParameterExpression OriginalParameter { get; }

    public Expression ConvertTo { get; }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (OriginalParameter == node)
        {
            return ConvertTo;
        }
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Sample of `Convert` method:

```
public Expression<Func<MyWrapper, bool>> Convert(Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> predicate)
{
    var originalParameter = predicate.Parameters[0];
    var newParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyWrapper));
    var ma = Expression.Property(newParameter, nameof(MyWrapper.MyClass));
    var converter = new ConverterVisitor(originalParameter, ma);
    var newBody = converter.Visit(predicate.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyWrapper, bool>>(newBody, newParameter);
}
```